# How can I check if an array has two or more of the same unknown strings in it?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How would I check in JavaScript if an array has two or more of the SAME values in it?

For example;

`['one','two','three']` -> false, because none the array items occur more than once.

`['one','one','two']` -> true, as 'one' occurs more than once.

`['one','one','one','two']` -> true, as 'one' occurs more than once.

`['askja', 'askja', 'askja', 'iamms']` -> true, as 'askja' occurs 3 times.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all non-unique values (i.e.: duplicate/more than one occurrence) in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/get-all-non-unique-values-i-e-duplicate-more-than-one-occurrence-in-an-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this:

1: Use the method Stevens Qiu suggested. If the length of the array and Set aren't equal, there was a repeat in the array. This is my favorite.

2: Iterate through the array. On each iteration, add that value to a hash. If the value is already in the hash, there was a repeat so return true.

3: Iterate through the array. On each iteration get the index of (indexOf()) the item and the last index (lastIndex()) of the item. If those values aren't equal, return true.

```js
const arr = ['hi', 'bye', 'hi'];
const arr2 = ['hi', 'bye', 'what'];

// Set size < arr length, so returns false
console.log(arr.length === new Set(arr).size);
// Set size == arr length, so returns true
console.log(arr2.length === new Set(arr2).size);
```

Comment: Thanks! This answered my question, but I forgot to ask one additional thing. How do I get the actual string that occurs twice?

Comment: To get the actual string, you'll be better off iterating as described in method 2 of the answer. When you find a key that already exists in the hash (Object.hasOwnProperty(key)) return the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through your array and push each element into a Set. If there are any collisions, then you know it has identical values in it.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to define a `map` that stores the existence (ie `true` if exists) of items values by key.

If once such item is already detected to exist via that map, you can deduce that multiple copies of a string exist in the input array:

```js
function hasMultipleCopies(arr) {
  
  /* 
  A temporary mapping that stores "true" for an key found to exist in
  arr 
  */
  const map = {};
  
  for(const item of arr) {
    if(map[item]) {
      /* 
      If mapping contains key/value for item, then current item has
      appeared at least twice in arr 
      */
      return true;
    }
    
    map[item] = true;
  }
  
  return false;  
}

console.log(hasMultipleCopies(['one','two','three']), "=== false")
console.log(hasMultipleCopies(['one','one','two']), "=== true")
console.log(hasMultipleCopies(['one','one','one','two']), "=== true")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the unique values, duplicates and find out if they are duplicates.

```
const array = [];

const uniqueItems = [...new Set(array)]

const duplicates = array.reduce((acc, item) => {
    return uniqueItems.includes(item) ? acc : [...acc, item];
}, []);

const hasDuplicate = duplicates.length > 0;
```